# Binary combinations of tuples

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of tuples (a,b) that can take one of 2 values, low or high. I am trying to find all unique combinations that are not related via symmetry. For instance, I would class (high, low)-- (low, high) equivalent to (low, high) -- (high, low). In other words, the order of the pairs around the -- is unimportant. In the below example there are $2^4=16$ possible combinations, although, by my symmetry rule, there are only 10 unique values. How can I calculate the number of possible values? Further, if my tuple contains more fields, (a,b,c,...) that can each take a binary high or low value, how many possible combinations can I have?

[image]

Comment: So, you have $2^2=4$ different pairs available.  You want to count how many pairs of these pairs there are, order irrelevant.  To do this, treat the set of pairs as the set we care about, and then use stars-and-bars over that set to get $\binom{2+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{5}{3}=10$

Comment: "*...Further, if my tuple contains more fields...*" you would have had $2^n$ different tuples available, making it $\binom{2+2^n-1}{2^n-1}$ following the same logic